# Spring Boot application with HikariCP and PgPool-II

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp, pgpool

I need to configure a failover cluster for Postgres. I want to use PgPool-II as failover for the failed instance of DB.

My application runs on Spring Boot 2 and uses HikariCP as datasource. HikariCP is a connection pool by itself, and PgPool uses its connection pool.

HikariCP allocate connection pool from PgPool, which gives connections from it's own pool. I understand that PgPool pool size must be greater than Hikari pool.

Can they work together? And is this a good practice to use both of them in conjuction?

Comment: Sure why not. PgPool is between the app and the database. They are not related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756239/not-able-to-open-connection-from-pgbouncer-connection-attempt-timed-out/57756405?r=SearchResults#57756405