# Is it possible to use Pgpool-II just for Load Balancing not for connection pooling?

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp, pgpool

We have a PostgreSQL 12 cluster with one master and two slave nodes. We are using Pgpool-II to load balance our SQL queries to our cluster. Our write queries go to the master and read queries go to the slave nodes.
We have a new Java application that uses HikariCP internally. So we want to disable the Pgpool-II connection pooling behaviour.
As it was explained on this link we should use one connection pooling abstraction.

[Not able to open connection from PgBouncer (Connection attempt timed out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756239/not-able-to-open-connection-from-pgbouncer-connection-attempt-timed-out/57756405#57756405)

When I examine the documents, I did not see a specific key just for disabling the connection pooling behaviour.

https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-connection-pooling.html.

The closest property I saw was the **connection_cache (boolean)** property.
Is setting this property to false disables the connection pooling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, settings **connection_cache**  to **false** will disables connection pooling and on each connection to pgpool-II from client pgpool-II create will create a new connection to backend database)